# What is the proper size of a sqlite database of 4 primary keys if I need fast query speed?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a sqlite database for map storage. The table is like this:

```
(x,y,zoom,type,image)
```

Where

```
(x,y,zoom,type)
```

is a combined primary key.
I would like to know the max size(rows) I could get for this database so that if I query for one image the query time is less than 100ms.
I am working on a intel I5 modern laptop.

Comment: That depends on the details of the OS, the amount of available cache, the system bus, the disk controller, and the disk.

Comment: For a modern laptop is there a rough number?

Comment: With an index (implied by the primary key), the database size does not really matter, and only these other factors affect the speed.